# Why do I get compilation errors instead of substitution failures when overloading operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am writing a Matrix class hierarchy, but get in trouble when overloading multiplication operators for multiplication of a matrix with a matrix, and scaling of a matrix by a scalar. I use std::enable_if_t to disambiguate which operator should get called depending on whether the types to be multiplied are matrices or not. Whether a variable is a matrix is determined by checking whether it inherits from an empty base class matrix_tag. 
Below is a fairly minimal reproducible sample of the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

// Forward declaration
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M> class Matrix;

// Empty base class for all matrices, to enable checking whether a type is a
// matrix
struct matrix_tag {};

template <typename MatrixType> struct is_matrix {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_base_of<matrix_tag, MatrixType>::value;
};

template <typename MatrixType>
constexpr bool Is_matrix = is_matrix<MatrixType>::value;

// Helper type function: The result of multiplying two generic types
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct product_type {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>());
};

// Convenience wrapper
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using Product_type = typename product_type<T1, T2>::type;

// Compile time dispatch for the result of matrix multiplications
template <typename Matrix1, typename Matrix2> struct matrix_product_type {
    static constexpr size_t N = Matrix1::number_of_rows;
    static constexpr size_t M = Matrix2::number_of_cols;
    static_assert(Matrix1::number_of_cols == Matrix2::number_of_rows);
    using element_type = Product_type<typename Matrix1::element_type,
                                      typename Matrix2::element_type>;
    using type = Matrix<element_type, N, M>;
};

// Convenience wrapper
template <typename Matrix1, typename Matrix2>
using Matrix_product_type =
    typename matrix_product_type<Matrix1, Matrix2>::type;

// Compile time dispatch for Matrix scaling
template <typename MatrixType, typename T> struct scaled_matrix_type {
    static constexpr size_t N = MatrixType::number_of_rows;
    static constexpr size_t M = MatrixType::number_of_cols;
    using element_type = Product_type<typename MatrixType::element_type, T>;
    using type = Matrix<element_type, N, M>;
};

// Convenience wrapper
template <typename MatrixType, typename T>
using Scaled_matrix_type = typename scaled_matrix_type<MatrixType, T>::type;

// Class definition
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M> class Matrix : public matrix_tag {
  public:
    // Types
    using element_type = T;
    // Traits
    static constexpr size_t number_of_rows = N;
    static constexpr size_t number_of_cols = M;

    // Default constructor
    Matrix() : elements_(N * M, 0) {}

    // Public access functions
    virtual const T &operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return elements_[row * number_of_cols + col];
    }
    virtual T &operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return const_cast<T &>(
            (*static_cast<const Matrix *>(this))(row, col));
    }

  private:
    // Element storage
    std::vector<T> elements_;
};

// Scaling

// Returns a new matrix with element_type reflecting the result of
// elementwise multiplication
template <typename MatrixType, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<(Is_matrix<MatrixType> && !Is_matrix<T>),
                 Scaled_matrix_type<MatrixType, T>>
operator*(const MatrixType &A, const T &x) {
    typename scaled_matrix_type<MatrixType, T>::type B = A;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != B.number_of_rows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != B.number_of_rows; ++j) {
            B(i, j) *= x;
        }
    }
    return B;
}

template <typename T, typename MatrixType>
std::enable_if_t<(!Is_matrix<T> && Is_matrix<MatrixType>),
                 Scaled_matrix_type<MatrixType, T>>
operator*(const T &x, const MatrixType &A) {
    return A * x;
}

// Matrix multiplication

template <typename Matrix1, typename Matrix2>
std::enable_if_t<(Is_matrix<Matrix1> && Is_matrix<Matrix2>),
                 Matrix_product_type<Matrix1, Matrix2>>
operator*(const Matrix1 &A, const Matrix2 &B) {
    typename matrix_product_type<Matrix1, Matrix2>::type C;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != A.number_of_rows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != B.number_of_cols; ++j) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k != A.number_of_cols; ++k) {
                C(i, j) += A(i, k) * B(k, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}

int main() {
    Matrix<double, 4, 3> A{};
    Matrix<float, 3, 2> B{};
    auto C = A * B;
}
```

Clang gives me a bunch of errors similar to this one:

> error: type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no
>   members
>       static_assert(Matrix1::number_of_cols == Matrix2::number_of_rows);

It seems to me that this should be a substitution failure rather than a compile error. What gives?

Comment: You want to make instantiations more lazy. i.e. get enable_if_t to give you scaled_matrix_type, and only access ::type outside of enable_if. This way the compiler does not need to instantiate scaled_matrix_type unless the condition in enable_if is true.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this piece of code:

```
template <typename Matrix1, typename Matrix2>
std::enable_if_t<(Is_matrix<Matrix1> && Is_matrix<Matrix2>),
                 Matrix_product_type<Matrix1, Matrix2>>
operator*(const Matrix1 &A, const Matrix2 &B) {...}
```

You seem to expect the second template argument to be discarded completely (without any validation) if the first template argument is false.

But what happens here is that both template arguments are validated first, and *then* the second argument is discarded if the condition turned out to be false.

Since using `Matrix_product_type` with non-matrix template parameters is a hard error (rather than a SFINAE-detectable error), you get a hard error before `enable_if_t` has a chance to kick in.

---

The most straightforward solution is to make the second template parameter for `enable_if_t` valid regardless of whether the condition is true or not.

One possible way to do that is:

```
template <typename Matrix1, typename Matrix2>
typename std::enable_if_t<(Is_matrix<Matrix1> && Is_matrix<Matrix2>),
                 matrix_product_type<Matrix1, Matrix2>>::type
operator*(const Matrix1 &A, const Matrix2 &B)
```

Note that I replaced `Matrix_product_type` (a type alias) with `matrix_product_type` (a `struct`).

This way `matrix_product_type<>::type` is not accessed unless the condition is true.

You might need to make similar changes to other overloads of `operator*` as well.